# How to add meta keywords in each Blogger post?

Tags: meta-tags, blogger, meta-description, meta-keywords

Recently I saw some "how to" articles about putting the meta keywords in each Blogger post individually. According these articles, you have to put some code many times, e.g. if the blog contains 100 posts, the code must be added 100 times. Please see the instruction: http://goo.gl/zB3lKG

I am afraid this trick might be risky, because the template will be overloaded by adding this code many times.

Is this method is still necessary, given that there is now an ability to add descriptions in the post editor?

Comment: Please do not use url softeners when linking to an external page. We prefer transparency for all links posted.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to work so hard for a meta-tag that is almost completely ignored except by Yandex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that the meta tags have been ignored by search engines but recently saw some new articles about this method and became interested.

I am going to add the meta descriptions through post editor.

Comment: That's really outdated advise on the article!

Answer (score 3):

[Google announced](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) in 2009 that they no longer use the meta keywords tags as a ranking factor, and Bing have since stated they could view it as a spam signal rather than a ranking aid.

I'm pretty sure that most other major search engines no longer use the meta keywords tag, apart from  [Yandex.](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.xml) and Baidu.

So I'd recommend not using the tag at all unless you are serious about ranking in Russia and China, and especally not taking advice from an article so clearly out of touch in current SEO by at least 6 years:

> Websites that are with the best Alexa ranking also use the same for
>   their pages. (GOOGLE, YAHOO, ETC). Meta Tags play a key role for their
>   optimized results.

!

Comment: I work with Google's web-search team & just wanted to confirm that the blog post from 2009 is still valid. From Google's point of view, there's no need to spend time on keyword meta tags.

Comment: SEO tested, John Mueller approved!